# how to push data in array if there is data in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-select2

Ok, i know it might be simple for some guys, but i am trying this for hours and have no success till now.

if i have data in this array

```
var tDataValues = {
    id: "TenantID",
    text: "FullName",
    username: "Username",
    cnic: 'CNIC'
}
```

i am sending this variable to the function

```
commonSelect2Templating(selector,url,tDataValues,minInputLength,placeholder);
```

> **Note:** I'm using Jquery Select2 (Sharing if it can help my question to understand.)

Then in that function in results Section i am trying to assign values

```
    results: function(data, page) {
        var newData = [];
        var length = data.length + 1;
        for(var i = 0; i<=length; i++){

        }
        $.each(data, function (index,value) {
            newData.push({
                id: value[tDataValues.id],  //id part present in data
                text: value[tDataValues.text]  //string to be displayed
            });
        });
        return { results: newData };
    }
```

This is the data coming from the Server:

```
[{"TenantID":"13","FullName":"Rameez Hassana","Username":"Rameez","CNIC":"16141-6321136-1"},{"TenantID":"14","FullName":"Syed Haider Hassan","Username":"pakistanihaider","CNIC":"17301-5856870-1"},{"TenantID":"15","FullName":"Demo Tenant No 1","Username":"tn1","CNIC":"15165-6156685-6"}]
```

**Coming to the The Problem:**
Right now all the magic is happening here.

```
$.each(data, function (index,value) {
    newData.push({
        id: value[tDataValues.id],  //id part present in data
        text: value[tDataValues.text]  //string to be displayed
    });
```

Its Telling the code which is id and which is text, and it is working perfectly fine.

Now the Problem here is function i am trying to make is Common Function for the select2,
and if i have more values from db, like now i am getting from database how to make a loop and set those values one by one to its proper context.
e-g
`tDataValues` holds the fieldName `cnic` and server is sending the fieldName `CNIC`
so how to make a loop that if cnic exist in both then it should simply assign,

i can do that manually

```
newData.push({
cnic: value[tDataValues.cnic]

        });
```

But like this it can not be a common function.

i can not simply make a logic how to implement this. did tried for hours but no success so far :(

Comment: `tDataValues` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for(var key in tDataValues) {
    newData.push({ key: value[tDataValues[key]]});
}
```

**Update:**

then create an object first and push it to the array:

```
for(var key in tDataValues) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value[tDataValues[key]];
  newData.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was one hell of a answer, Awesome, cuz it shows very specific data when i try to ouput using console.log like `console.log(key+' : '+value[tDataValues[key]]);`, but problem is using `newData.push({ key: value[tDataValues[key]]});` it don't get the the key value for its index, its just put key as static and i get this in result.
`[{"key":"13"},{"key":"Rameez Hassana"},{"key":"Rameez"},{"key":"16141-6321136-1"},{"key":"14"},{"key":"Syed Haider Hassan"},{"key":"pakistanihaider"},{"key":"17301-5856870-1"},{"key":"15"},{"key":"Demo Tenant No 1"},{"key":"tn1"},{"key":"15165-6156685-6"}]`

Comment: i needed to do little changes to your code, and wallah my problem solved. You are awesome. Thankyou. Many Many Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

check this, hope it helps

```
  var mainData =[{"TenantID":"13","FullName":"Rameez Hassana","Username":"Rameez","CNIC":"16141-6321136-1"},{"TenantID":"14","FullName":"Syed Haider Hassan","Username":"pakistanihaider","CNIC":"17301-5856870-1"},{"TenantID":"15","FullName":"Demo Tenant No 1","Username":"tn1","CNIC":"15165-6156685-6"}];

var newData =[];

for(var i =0;i<mainData.length;i++){ 
    for(var key in mainData[i]) { 
        var tempObj ={}; 
        tempObj[key] = mainData[i][key];
        newData.push(tempObj);
    }   
}
```

OUTPUT IS  : [{"TenantID":"13"},{"FullName":"Rameez Hassana"},{"Username":"Rameez"},{"CNIC":"16141-6321136-1"},{"TenantID":"14"},{"FullName":"Syed Haider Hassan"},{"Username":"pakistanihaider"},{"CNIC":"17301-5856870-1"},{"TenantID":"15"},{"FullName":"Demo Tenant No 1"},{"Username":"tn1"},{"CNIC":"15165-6156685-6"}]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i think you did not got my question correctly, i do not want to specify `CNIC` or `FullName`, i want it to be selected automatically using loop, @artm gave really great answer but still i am getting the key error.
I hope you understand what i am trying to achieve..

Comment: @SizzlingCode hey i've edited my answer , check if i got ur question now . Thanks :)

Comment: Many many thanks, but i tried and realized that output i am getting is not right.
output i want is this.
`[{"TenantID":"13","FullName":"Rameez Hassana","Username":"Rameez","CNIC":"16141-6321136-1"},{"TenantID":"14"},{"FullName":"Syed Haider Hassan"},{"Username":"pakistanihaider"},{"CNIC":"17301-5856870-1"}]`